# How to Assign partition key while Migrating Data from SQL to Cosmos Db in Azure Cosmos DB Data Migration Tool

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have Downloaded the [Azure Cosmos DB Data Migration Tool](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/documentdb-data-migration-tool/) from here.
i'm Migrating the Sql Data to Cosmos DB. while Using the Migration Tool.
[Source Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5RvL.png) [image: Target Information]

What Should i provide in the partition Key Field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **cosmosdb**, The **`PartitionKey`** is a property that will exist on every single object that is best used to group similar objects together.

According to **[`docs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data)**,

> Specify the document property you wish to use as the Partition Key (if
>   Partition Key is left blank, documents are sharded randomly across the
>   target collections).

Collections over 10GB, partition key is required.

In order to understand more on PartionKey read **[`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data)**.

Comment: So, should i provide the Column name from the Sql Scripts which hold the partition key value ? @Sajeetharan

Comment: Row 1 Microsoft.DataTransfer.DocumentDb.Exceptions.FailedToCreateDocumentException: PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.DataTransfer.Core.Service.DataTransferAction.<TransferDataItem>d__d.MoveNext() in f:\_Bld\12470\6357\Sources\_repo\Core\Microsoft.DataTransfer.Core\Service\DataTransferAction.cs:line 79 Following error is Shown if the Collection has a partition key. @sajeetharan

Comment: Value that you will specify for PartitionKey in the data migration tool is the path to the JSON property in the document. For example, if the column name in your SQL Server table is `StateCode` that you designate as PartitionKey, the value you will specify here is `/StateCode`.

Comment: i have tried same as /stateCode but it shows the same Error @Gaurav Mantri

Comment: i have no Idea but while Selecting Export To =DocumentDB-Sequential record Import(Partitioned Collection) instead of Bulk Import without "/"  to column name works for me. Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you migrating one table or multiple tables into a single collection?

I recommend using an Unique index that is exists in all the tables.

Alternately you can create a new partition key